# distinguish rootfolder by folderid in google api

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am working with google apis and now need to undrestand if my result(I know the filde is a folder), is a root folder in google drive hierarchy( i mean the first folder which we see at first page of google drive) by having folder id till i could lead action to other specefic function. Do you know how can I find root folder by folder id. I know how can i find folder id by parsing folders but have no idea about reverse acttion.

```
$("#folderName" + folderId).click(function(){
                            //debugger;                              
                            $("#previousFolder").fadeIn();                                                                
                            navigategoogleDFolder(folderId);                               
                        });
}
```

You can see how i get folderid. but inside of the func i need to learn if the folder is root or not like

```
if(fodlerid.isRoot == false)
{
  func(fodlerid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder),

> You can use the alias `root` to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided.